# Android Customize Wifi Scan

Tags: android, android-wifi, wifimanager

I am interested in scanning only a particular set of frequencies for a particular time interval (this is different from scanning interval in android api). Is there any  high level api

or

user to kernel space communication interfaces, mechanisms (sysfs,iotctl,mmap etc.) (in a rooted device) that can allow me to specify the set of frequencies to be scanned for a particular interval of time. If I understand correctly the device supplicant carries this information?

Would very much appreciate if anyone can point me in right direction.

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Did you ever find anything?  I'm looking for something along these lines as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See my [answer on android.sx](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/46639/scan-a-single-channel-to-measure-rssi-of-a-specific-ap-when-not-associated/46765#46765). Basically, [install `iw`](http://www.onlyxool.net/porting-iw-tools-to-android/) on your device and then call:

```
iw dev wlan0 scan freq 2417
```

However, I do not know how this interacts with the supplicant/connection manager. We use it to measure RSSI only.