# Can I change android wifi scan parameters?

Tags: android, wifi

Seems like a simple question but I couldn't find the answer for it easily...

When I do a wifi scan (`wifi.startscan()`), can I control how it operates?
can I control the channels it searches?
the duration it stays in each channel?

Comment: have you took a look at the android [developer](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/WifiManager.html) site for wifimanager?

Comment: why ofcourse... all I have in there is: "Request a scan for access points. Returns immediately. The availability of the results is made known later by means of an asynchronous event sent on completion of the scan."

Comment: yes, that's all. and I think there's no further explanation. at least this is what I think :)

Comment: Doesn't seem like a programming question. If it is, you might want to rephrase it in terms of a real-world programming issue you're having - otherwise your question (while perfectly valid) is [not a good fit](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#questions) for SO.

Comment: I don't understand why this is not a valid programming question. I'm using an API function but asking what configuration can I change to control it better...

Comment: but if it makes anybody happy - I rephrased the question...

Answer (score 0):

If you use the shell and are willing to install `iw`, you can at least [control the frequencies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10680867/android-customize-wifi-scan/17028425#17028425) you scan. I'm not sure about the duration though.

Answer (score 0):

This may come too late but here goes: I read a paper from the PERCOM conference this year, called "Incremental Wi-Fi Scanning for Energy-Efficient Localization". They basically rooted the Android phone and changed the API so that they could accomplish exactly what you're describing (scanning only in certain frequencies for energy management reasons).