# quicker WiFi scan rate to obtain rssi changes android

Tags: android, wifi, rate, rssi, network-scan

I am trying to increase the wifi scan rate but with the method wifi.startscan and getting the info of the list result returned, i dont see that the rssi change each 2 seconds. My question is if it is possible to get a low rate scan of the rssi and if it is possible how could i do it.

Answer (score 1):

The scan rate is so low, because the scan takes that long. The only way you can reduce the time a scan takes, is to [scan on a subset of available frequencies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10680867/android-customize-wifi-scan/17028425#17028425).

Comment: You could also reduce the scan dwell time per channel, but dropping this much below 150ms risks missing beacon frames.

Comment: @alfwatt Do you have a command how to do that? (Or is this hardware specific?)